# Solr multi-word suggest gives zero results when full word is used

Tags: solr, autosuggest

Field Definition

```
<field name="programDescriptionLookup"
       type="suggest_simple"
       indexed="true"
       stored="false"
       multiValued="true"/>
```

Field Type & Copy field

```
<copyField source="programDescription" dest="programDescriptionLookup"/>

<fieldType name="suggest_simple" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

2 documents exist with the following values for the field

```
<field name="programDescription">Great program for kids</field>
<field name="programDescription">Excellent program for Technology</field>
```

When I search for

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core/posdSuggest?q=progra+fo

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">3</int>
</lst>
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions">
<lst name="progra">
<int name="numFound">1</int>
<int name="startOffset">0</int>
<int name="endOffset">6</int>
<arr name="suggestion">
<str>program</str>
</arr>
</lst>
<lst name="fo">
<int name="numFound">1</int>
<int name="startOffset">7</int>
<int name="endOffset">9</int>
<arr name="suggestion">
<str>for</str>
</arr>
</lst>
<str name="collation">program for</str>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

When I search with full words, I get no results

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core/posdSuggest?q=program+for

<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

What configuration change is required to get results for both queries `progra+fo` & `program+for`?